# Meaning of $F = T(E) ⊕ Ker(T^*)$? Espacially the notation $⊕$?

Tags: notation

I am not get used to with the notation $⊕$. I met this notation in the document [SPHERICAL HARMONICS AND HOMOGENEOUS HARMONIC POLYNOMIALS](http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/m435f07/m435sphericalharmonics.pdf) with **($*$)** $F = T(E) ⊕ Ker(T^*)$ page $3$. Could anyone be able to tell me the meaning of that notation and another way to understand **($*$)** in term of the notation?

Comment: You could think that $F$ consists in ordered pairs $\langle x,y\rangle$, where $x\in T(E)$ and $y\in Ker(T*)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol $\oplus$ stands for the [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) operation on vector spaces. Moreover here we are dealing with an orthogonal direct sum of inner product subspaces, meaning that the subspaces to be summed are mutually orthogonal with respect to the ambient inner product. Therefore $F = T(E) \oplus \ker T^*$ means that elements $f \in F$ can be identified with pairs $(u,v) \in T(E) \oplus \ker T^*$, with $u \in T(E)$ and $v \in \ker T^*$, and that $T(E)$ is orthogonal to $\ker T^*$.

To see this, consider the orthogonal projection $P$ onto the subspace $T(E)$, $P:F \to T(E)$. Then every element $f \in F$ may be uniquely decomposed as $f = P(f) + (f - P(f))$. The first term belongs to $P(F) = T(E)$, and the second term belongs to $\ker P = \ker T^*$ (the kernel of $P$ consists of elements orthogonal to $T(E)$). Note that we identify $F^*$ with $F$ via the inner product.

Comment: Could you tell me how to define the orthogonal projection $P$?

Comment: @JeanCharrue One way is to define $P(f)$ to be the unique vector in $T(E)$ such that $ \{ \| f - t\| : t \in T(E)\}$ attains its minimum at $t = P(f)$. In other words, it is the vector in $T(E)$ that is *closest* to $f$.

Comment: @JeanCharrue Alternatively, in a finite-dimensional inner product space, and given an $n$-dimensional subspace with a given *orthonormal* basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$, we may define $P(v) = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v,e_i \rangle e_i$.

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand!

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is a vector space and $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$, then we say that $V=U\oplus W$ provided that (i) $U+W=V$ and (ii) $U\cap W=\{0\}$. If $V$ is an inner product space, we can form an orthogonal direct sum decomposition by replacing (ii) with (ii') $(u,w)=0$ for all $u\in U$ and $w\in W$.

For example, if $V$ is the vector space of real $n\times n$ matrices, $U$ is the subspace of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices, and $W$ is the subspace of skew-symmetric $n\times n$ matrices, then $V=U\oplus W$.

Another way of thinking about a direct sum decomposition $V=U\oplus W$ is that every vector $v\in V$ can be written as a sum $v=u+w$ with $u\in U,w\in W$ in exactly one way.

By the way, this sort of decomposition is sometimes called an *internal* direct sum, to distinguish it from the related notion of an *external* direct sum.